# what is the difference between Document and Database in Frappe framework?

Tags: python, database, document, frappe

I'm a newbie in the Frappe framework, in the Frappe documentation, I encountered two different ways that can store data which are: **"Document and Database API"** all I know is that both of them are used to store data into them somehow.

what I need to know is that:

1. what is the difference between database and document to store data or why don't use one method to store data (*database for example*)?

when I create a new doctype (e.g TestApp) that doctype will be created like so:

```
class TestApp(Document):
    pass
```

and if we assumed that this model has the following field which is called **"my_data"**, so we can print this field into that model like so:

```
class TestApp(Document):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("data is: ", self.my_data)
        super(TestApp, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

which will create the second question which is:

2. how could "**Document**" store and call the data (my_data) from it?

Comment: In [documentation](https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/api/document) I see `Document represents a single record in the database table`

Comment: and what is that mean?

Comment: `Database = many Documents` or `one Document = one row/record in Database`

Answer (score 2):

Frappe provides a hybrid App Data Modelling structure, with an ORM and Query Builder out of the box.

The `Document` interface (via `frappe.get_doc`) is the ORM. Through this, each record (a row in the Table) is a Document. Essentially, a Document is an instance of the DocType *(Document Type)* which acts as a sort of template. You can hook into a Document's lifecycle through this.

As for the DB APIs and the Query Builder(s), they offer a thin layer over standard DBMS protocols. You can use them to efficiently update data outside of the Document lifecycle. These are essentially thin Python wrappers around SQL.

---

The creation of each DocType makes a new table, each new field corresponds to a new column and each Document is a row. Every (non-custom) DocType tracks it's schema using `.json` files that you'll find with the controller. This makes it easy to share your apps and manage migrations.

The document returned by a `frappe.get_doc` call contains the data maintained in the DBMS and the methods defined in it's controller. You can checkout the source code for [Document](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/blob/5b7e7efb57ad83cd9f6450e60d7f2dd4e691304c/frappe/model/document.py#L80) to see how the magic happens.

---

Documentation References:

- [Document Lifecycle Hooks](https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/basics/doctypes/controllers#controller-hooks)
- [Database APIs](https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/api/database)
- [Document APIs](https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/api/document)